# How to make GL_EXT_draw_buffers extension available?

Tags: webgl, glsles, webgl-extensions

I want to use the WEBGL_draw_buffers extension. Besides enabling the extension by `gl.getExtension('WEBGL_draw_buffers');` in the JavaScript, one apparently has to enable the extension in the shader as well by using the directive `#extension GL_EXT_draw_buffers : require`. However, whereas my WebGL implementation seems to support the WEBGL_draw_buffers extension (also according to [WebGL Extension Viewer](http://renderingpipeline.com/webgl-extension-viewer/)), the shader does not. I'm getting the following error:

`'GL_EXT_draw_buffers' : extension is not supported`

Is there a way to fix this? I already updated my graphics card driver. I get the error both, with a dedicated AMD Graphics Card (that also supports OpenGL 4.5) and with an integrated Intel Graphics Chip.

Comment: post some code. Also does [the official test for WEBGL_draw_buffers](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/conformance/extensions/webgl-draw-buffers.html?webglVersion=1&quiet=0) work on your machine?

Comment: @gman Looks as if it's a Firefox problem. The test passes in Chrome but fails in FF at `test that gl_FragColor does not broadcast unless extension is enabled in fragment shader` where attachments 1-7 are: `FAIL attachment 1 should be 0,255,0,255
at (0, 0) expected: 0,255,0,255 was 255,0,0,255`. FF is up-to-date. Any suggestions?

Comment: File a bug? https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/